# Why I'm getting DOCTYPE Error in FireBug in asp.net Web Application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, iis

net web application.

All is working fine when I deploy the application on my PC and on Server 1, But When I deploy the application on Server 2 and try to access it from my PC. Its launched but I get Syntax Error in FireBug. It says

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E
```

I'm not able to understand why this error is coming. I'm trying to find the root cause behind this since morning, But not even a single clue.

This is my aspx code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateUserPageIfTableEmpty.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="false"
    Inherits="PaymentControllerGUI.CreateUserPageIfTableEmpty" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link id="Link1" rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" runat="server" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Somewhere I have read that this could be because of script tag(.js). So I'm posting script tag too.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

Please help me to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Scripts/jquery.min.js` (or some other script in the page) is resolving as an HTML document instead of a JavaScript program.